# Grouped graph with error bars

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, errorbar

I need to reproduce this plot in R with ggplot2[image]

Does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are working with means and standard deviations for your error bars you can do something like this (I created a data frame that I thought might look something like yours):

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(num = runif(160, min = 0, max = 1),
             class = c(rep(c(rep("t-logistic", 4), rep("NSC", 4), 
                             rep("Poisson", 4), rep("PCC", 4), rep("Sparse PCC", 4),
                             rep("Sup. PCC", 4), rep("Sparse PLS", 4), rep("SVM", 4)), 5)),
             cat = c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 40)))


df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(class, cat) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(num), sd = sd(num))


ggplot(df1, aes(class, mean, color = cat))+
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(class, ymin = (mean - 2*sd), ymax = (mean + 2*sd)), 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.6))+
  theme_bw()
```

that will give you this graph:
[image]